# How to search mutliple values separated by comma

Tags: javascript, php

I am getting data from database using `datatable` referenced by this page https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

In that table below I have input fields to each column for search box.
For instance we have columns like this `First Name, Last Name, Position ...` etc in below `Fname search, lname search and Position search..` etc. Here when I search for `First Name` from `Fname search` box I am getting result, means if I search for `mike` I am getting mike data.

Here my query is when I search multiple names at time with comma separation means if search from `Fname search` box `mike,jack` I should get mike row data and jack row data in that table using JavaScript.

Comment: Use regular expressions using the search API. See https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html

Comment: it depends on how your server side script (that returns the values) looks like - could you provide this script?

Comment: @SteBächler thanks for your response ,you can see this page  https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html .My script like that only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data is filtered on the server side, you will have to change that in the ssp.class.php file.

try searching for this:

```
        if ( isset($request['search']) && $request['search']['value'] != '' ) {
            $str = $request['search']['value'];

            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
                $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
                $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

                if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' ) {
                    $binding = self::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                    $globalSearch[] = "`".$column['db']."` LIKE ".$binding;
                }
            }
        }
```

and replace it with that:

```
        if ( isset($request['search']) && $request['search']['value'] != '' ) {
            $str = $request['search']['value'];

            $parts = explode(",",$str);
            foreach ($parts as $part) {
                $part = trim($part);
                if (strlen($part) == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                    $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
                    $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
                    $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];


                    if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' ) {
                        $binding = self::bind( $bindings, '%'.$part.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                        $globalSearch[] = "`".$column['db']."` LIKE ".$binding;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much ,it is working perfect .